# A question about the relation between the combination and the type of objects: Should the objects be incongruous?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

I'd been taught that the number of ways that we can select $k$ objects from $n$ nonidentical objects, is given by (regardless of order):

$$C_{n}^{k}=\frac{n!}{k!*(n-k)!}$$

I have a very simple question about this matter:

> Is it really obligatory that the objects are nonidentical?

If so, why in the ball-examples we use combination? For instance, consider we have $4$ red balls and $3$ green balls in a container. Then, we are asked to say the number of ways that we can select two balls from the container. As you know, we immediately say that the number of ways that we can choose $2$ balls from the container is $C_{7}^{2}$. **However, all the balls are not nonidentical. With this regard, what would be the number of ways that we can choose $2$ red balls from $6$ red balls? Is it $C_{2}^{6}$?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it only works if the items are non-indentical.   $^n\mathrm C_r$ counts the *distinct* ways to select $r$ elements from a set of $n$ *indistinguishable* elements.   If the elements were *identical*, there would only be one *distinct* way to select $r$ of them.   (Assuming integer values and $0\leq r\leq n$.)

**Note:** Physically the balls will be unique entities, but what we are counting is the arrangements of *identifiable traits*.   (Such as colours.)

---

PS: ${^n\mathrm C_r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$.   I've encountered it written as $\mathrm C^n_r$, but always with the superscript corresponding to the numerator while the subscript to the denominator.   It would be confusing for a text to present it otherwise.

Comment: So, you say, since the balls are in the container and we have no idea about them, they are indistinguishable. don't you? Thus, what would be the number of ways that we can choose 2 balls from 6 red balls which are in a container? $C_{6}^{2}$?

Comment: There is only one distinct way to select two colours from six identical red hues; you select red and red.

Answer (score 0):

Working on the case that you sugested, you have three ways to choose those balls:

$$(red,red), (red,green), (green,green)$$

You will always fall in one of those cases. So, to be non-identical really matters.

Like @Graham said:

Physically the balls will be unique entities, but what we are counting is the arrangements of identifiable traits.   (Such as colours.)

Comment: I know that the colors are responsible for making them different things. I'm saying that why although there 4 red (read identical because they have the same color) and 3 green (read identical because they have the same color), we treat them like 7 different colors? If that's the method, therefore the answer of my last question will be $C_{6}^{2}$

Comment: It depends on what you are counting.  The distinct ways to select unique balls *or* the distinct ways to select colours.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I define the indentical balls as the balls with the same color. I got confused :(

Comment: That is contrary to the normal usage of the word "unique".

Comment: @GrahamKemp Let's consider the only single difference between the balls is their color. I mean they look identical from the physical point of view.

Comment: Suppose that I give you one red ball and one green ball. After that I give another red and green ball. Do you see any difference?

Comment: But if I give you one red ball and one green ball. After that I give you two red balls. That's for sure a different choice. Don't you think so?

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento Yes, the sect's members has increased. In the new situation you will put different numbers in the combination formula.

Comment: Is it clear now for you?

Comment: No. Lets make it simple, if you add another red and green then you will have $C_{8}^{2}$ which is indeed different from $C_{6}^{2}$, considering the new situation made in your three previous comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49432/discussion-between-arnaldo-nascimento-and-cardinal).